# calculate payment according to the number of children

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, count

below is my tables in database.

[image]

I wanted to calculate payment according to number of children.

Let's say payment = $100 per year. It should times by number of children.

I have a label which will display the number of children. Now, the sql query I did so far as below but i know it sounds very wrong. I'm just learning sql now. Please assist me.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child WHERE ParentId=ParentId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cracking my head for 1 hour. I solved the query myself.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child c INNER JOIN Parent par on c.ParentId = par.ParentId WHERE par.UserId = ?`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` the two tables `Child`, `Parent` and `Payment`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      p.parentId,
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      COUNT(c.ChildId) AS NOfChilderen 
    FROM Child  AS c
    INNER JOIN Parent  AS p  ON c.ParentId = p.ParentId
    GROUP BY p.parentId,
             p.FirstName,
             p.LastName
)
SELECT 
  c.parentId,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName,
  NOfChilderen * p.PaymentAmount AS TotalAmount
FROM CTE AS C
INNER JOIN Payment AS p ON p.UserId  = p.UserId;
```

The `CTE` ([Common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) will calculate the no of childeren for each parent by joining the two tables `Parent` and `child`, then it will join with the other table `payment` and calculate the total amount for each parent.

Comment: it seems complicated. Could you shorten it ? because i wanted to display the value in a label only.

Comment: @t3es - This will calculate the total payment for all the parents by multiply the count of childeren with the `PaymentAmount` column. Is this true? How do you want to calculate the total payment? Do you want only one value or for all the rows? Can you please give a sample data and the desired output? It will be very helpful to understand what you want to do. Thanks :)

Comment: @t3es - Do you want to get that for a specific parent or for all parents? If you want to do that for a specific parent, you have to pass the `parentId` to your query like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child WHERE ParentId = @ParentId`. If you want to do this for all the parents, you have to remove the `where` clause like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PARENT.PARENTID, COUNT(*)*100 AS PAYMENT, COUNT(*) AS NUMBEROFCHILDREN
FROM PARENT LEFT JOIN CHILDREN ON PARENT.PARENNID=CHILDREN.CHILDRENID
GROUP BY PARENT.PARENTID
```

I used left join as soon as you can have parent with no children?